# Update bound property in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

**Quick description of my setup:**

*Disclaimer: The code is only to show what I want to do. The command binding for instance is done with event triggers etc. I'm pretty sure this wouldn't even build, but I didn't want to waste space.*

My View:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsFavorite, Converter={StaticResource FavoriteConverter}" Tap="{Binding FavoriteCommand, CommandParameter={Binding}}"/>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand<Item> Favorite
    {
       get
       {
           return new RelayCommand<Item>(item =>
                {
                    item.IsFavorite = !item.IsFavorite;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(string.Empty);
                };
        }
     }
}
```

My Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
}
```

****My Question:****

How can I get the IsFavorite-Property to update without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged? It's a model class, and I wouldn't like creating a ViewModel for the sole purpose of updating one property. I thought that calling PropertyChanged with an empty string would update everything, but alas it didn't.

****My Solution:****

```
public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Item Model { get; private set; }
    public bool IsFavorite
    {
        get { return Model.IsFavorite; }
        set
        {
            Model.IsFavorite = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsFavorite");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are binding to the value and expect it to be changing at runtime, then you should really implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` since WPF's binding system uses that interface to know when it needs to update.

But with that said, you might be able to get away with raising a `PropertyChange` notification for the entire `Items` collection, although I'm not entirely sure that would work because the actual collection itself hasn't changed, only a property of one of the items inside the collection. And WPF usually knows not to bother re-evaluating a property if it doesn't actually change.

```
RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
```

If it doesn't work, you could probably remove the item and re-add it to trigger a `CollectionChange` notification, however that also might not work and may cause other problems depending on your application design.

```
// I may have the exact syntax wrong here
var index = Items.IndexOf(item);
var tmp = Items[index];
Items.Remove(tmp);
Items.Add(tmp, index);
```

But it would really just be best to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `Item` class.

Comment: Raising property changed on Items wouldn't work if String.Empty doesn't work, and adding / removing is even more unnecessary than what I wanted to do. I guess I'll create a ItemViewModel wrapper for the Item class.

Comment: @SBoss Why not just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Item` model? It seems like unnecessary complexity to create a wrapper for the data item just to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Design patterns are there to make our lives easier by providing a set of guidelines (not rules) that often make development easier, and blindly following the rules in cases where they don't make sense isn't really using them correctly.

Comment: My boss would freak if a model implements INotifyPropertyChanged.. He's a hardline MVVM guy, I doubt he'd listen to me explain. Thanks for taking the time to explain for other viewers, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: `RaisePropertyChanged("Items");` and make Items collection ObservableCollection.

Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is better.